# Copiar, Colar e Recortar um Array de inteiros em java usando Clipboard?

Tags: java, array, área-de-transferência

Saudações pessoal,

Estava tentando realizar os processos de Copiar, Colar e Recortar utilizando um Array de inteiros no Java, porém encontrei muita dificuldade e pouco material (principalmente em português).

Comment: Legal sua iniciativa, mas este é um site de Perguntas e Respostas e não um fórum. Você pode fazer uma pergunta, e postar sua solução como resposta, será uma contribuição legal. Veja aqui um pouco mais sobre como o site funciona: [Tour]. Leia também o [FAQ da comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699), que tem muitas orientações úteis. Lembre-se que você pode [Edit] a pergunta, copiando seu conteudo para uma nova resposta, deixando na postagem inicial apenas a indagação de como fazer o que sua postagem propõe. Assim, ficará no formato adequado e ajudará outras pessoas.

Comment: Valeu pela observação, primeiro post... sabe como é. rsrsrs

Comment: Agora ficou legal. Inclusive, depois pode dar um clique no **✓** verdinho do lado da sua resposta, pra marcar como solução aceita. Se quiser, depois, pode dar uma elaboradinha na pergunta com as eventuais dificuldades que teve antes de conseguir. Mas o passo fundamental, você já deu. E seja bem-vindo. Depois dê uma lida no [meta], que é nosso "site que discute o site" principal. Enquanto aqui nós fazemos perguntas e respostas sobre programação, lá nós discutimos como funciona o site, e fazemos eventuais sugestões de melhorias e correções.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui desenvolver, segue abaixo o código:

```
public class CopiarColarArray {

public void copiar(){
    int[] data = new int[]{1,2,3,9872,5374,57};
    MinhaClasseSelection selection = new MinhaClasseSelection(data);
    Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    cb.setContents(selection, selection);      
}

public void recortar(){
    int[] data = new int[]{1,2,3};
    MinhaClasseSelection selection = new MinhaClasseSelection(data);
    Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    cb.setContents(selection, selection);      
    data = new int[]{};
}

public void colar(){
    Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    try {
        Transferable t = cb.getContents(this);
        if(t.isDataFlavorSupported(MinhaClasseSelection.ARRAY_INT_DATA_FLAVOR)){
            int[] data = (int[])(t.getTransferData(MinhaClasseSelection.ARRAY_INT_DATA_FLAVOR));
            for (int i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Array: "+data[i]);
            }
        }                
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CopiarColarArray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CopiarColarArray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

/* Minha classe perfonalizada do Selection */
public static class MinhaClasseSelection implements Transferable, ClipboardOwner {
    private int[] intData;

    public final static DataFlavor ARRAY_INT_DATA_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(int[].class, "Array int");
    public final static DataFlavor[] flavors ={ARRAY_INT_DATA_FLAVOR};

    public MinhaClasseSelection(int[] data){
        intData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return flavors;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor df) {
        for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
            if (df.equals(flavors[i])){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor df) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if (df.equals(ARRAY_INT_DATA_FLAVOR)){
            return intData;
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clpbrd, Transferable t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

  }
}
```